# Unicode version and conformance info in R

Tags: r, unicode

Unicode has many versions.

Current version is 14.

Package `utf8` documentation explicitly says it supports 10.0.0.

But what about R itself? I can not find any comment on which version of Unicode R supports.

Unicode has different level of support it can get.

As I print out `'\u0061\u20de\u0308\u20dd'` in R studio,

the output is not what unicode 14 guideline says for enclosing marks.

So for complete specification of unicode support,

I think R should say about the level it supports unicode, but I could not find any for this info either. So anyone knows any info about it?

Comment: Disregard Unicode conformance (if you check in Unicode, you see that conformance is very relative: they expect nobody will be full conformant, but they ask to be conformant on small ranges. And your problem has nothing to do with R. R prints transparently the Unicode. You should check your OS documentation about the support: it is the OS (or the different display and shaping and font libraries) which are supposed to print it correctly.

Comment: Actually, that was another question: who handles the unicode? I am not sure if you are right because Unicode needs a lot of fonts, and Visual studio can set fall-back fonts(I dont think R studio can). So is it really OS that renders the character? Here is another example: I am using firafont and `cat('\u0061\u20de\u0308\u20dd')` results in an alphabet "a" plus two rectangles, nevertheless `nchar('\u0061\u20de\u0308\u20dd', type='width')` is just 1, which is Unicode conformant. As I read the doc, it says it is the implementation problem...

Comment: Anyway if you are really right about it, can you give me reference?

Comment: I do not have much reference. In Linux (Debian), Gnu R uses Pango (which uses in this case Harfbuzz). The first is for layout and rendering text, and the latter is the shaping (exact glyph in font and its position). I do not know if R uses one of the two microsoft shaping engines in Windows. OTOH I'm surprised that what you are requesting is not compatible to Unicode 10 (U+20DE and U+20DD) exist from Unicode 1.0!). Note R support of unicode is about splitting words etc. (so you have support only for language included in Unicode 10)

Comment: Here is what I found from https://icu.unicode.org: The C and C++ languages and many operating system environments do not provide full support for Unicode and standards-compliant text handling services.  The ICU4C libraries fills in this gap. ICU4C provides an open, flexible, portable foundation for applications to use for their software globalization requirements. ICU4C closely tracks industry standards, including Unicode and CLDR (Common Locale Data Repository).

Comment: I guess unicode is an abstract protocol and ICU4C or ICU4J is a particular implementation of unicode standards. It confused me a while. So I guess unicode support is on a package-level in R.